# Assigning the same value to 2 different Properties using CommandLine Parser nuget C#

Tags: c#, command-line, command-line-parser

I have these 2 properties:

```
[Option("IpAddress1")]
public string IpAddress1 { get; set; }
[Option("IpAddress2")]
public string IpAddress2 { get; set; }
```

and when running with these parameters:

```
--IpAddress1 "1.1.1.1" --IpAddress2" 1.1.1.1"
```

I get the "MissingValueOptionError".

when running with:

```
--IpAddress1 "1.1.1.1" --IpAddress2 "1.1.1.2"
```

everything works fine.

Any idea why?

CommandLineParser nuget:
https://github.com/gsscoder/commandline

Update1:
It looks like it has something to do with setting the "_.IgnoreUnknownArguments = true;"

```
new Parser(
            _ =>
            {
                _.CaseSensitive = false;
                _.HelpWriter = helpWriter;
                _.IgnoreUnknownArguments = true;
            }).
            ParseArguments<T>(commandLineArguments).
            WithParsed(_ => parsedFromCommandLineArguments = _).
            WithNotParsed(
                _ =>
                {
                    parseSucceeded = false;
                    if (_.Any(
                        __ => __.Tag == ErrorType.HelpRequestedError ||
                              __.Tag == ErrorType.HelpVerbRequestedError))
                    {
                        isHelpRequestedDetected = true;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Shouldn't syntax be `--IpAddress1 "1.1.1.1" --IpAddress2 "1.1.1.2"`?

Comment: You re correct. I changed it. It still behaves the same. I also tried with other string (e.g. "aaa" "aaa" vs "aaa" "aab") and it still behaved the same way.

Comment: updated the question with something a bit more concrete. It looks like it has got something to do with setting the IgnoreUnknownArguments property.

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like it's a bug in the CommandLine Parser Nuget.

I ended up solving it by removing the:

```
_.IgnoreUnknownArguments = true;
```

so now it looks like:

```
new Parser(
        _ =>
        {
            _.CaseSensitive = false;
            _.HelpWriter = helpWriter;
        })...
```

and added a helper method before that cleans the unknown arguments that I don't want to be parsed (for me they are the ones not starting with the "--" syntax):

```
var filteredCommandLineArguments = new List<string>();
var isValueExpected = false;
foreach (var commandLineArgument in commandLineArguments)
{
    if (isValueExpected)
    {
       isValueExpected = false;
       filteredCommandLineArguments.Add(commandLineArgument);
       continue;
    }
    if (commandLineArgument.StartsWith("--"))
    {
       isValueExpected = true;
       filteredCommandLineArguments.Add(commandLineArgument);
    }
}
```

And now if a user enters an unexpected value with the "--" syntax than it's ok, otherwise not.